# String to Integer conversions in shell script and back to String

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to do String to Integer conversion, operate that integer and back to string in shell.

I have

```
input_sub=000
while [ -d $input_dir ]
do
    echo $input_sub
    # HERE I would like to fist convert 000 to 0
    # then add 1 to it 0-> 1
    # then convert that 1 to 001 
done
```

Don't mind much about the while condition.
I would like to do what is described in the comments.
How can I do this?

Comment: `printf "%d" "000"` and back `printf "%03d" "0"`

Comment: Not sure if this helps your use case, but you could use brace expansions as well, like this: `for dir in {000..010}; do echo "dir: $dir"; done`

Comment: I would start with `input_sub=0`, then convert to a 0-padded string as necessary, rather than going in the other direction.

Comment: Other than things like leading zeroes, this is what bash always does with arithmetic. The shell pretty much only has strings, so variables are always stored as strings; when you do arithmetic with them, it parses them as integers, does the math, then converts the result back to a string for storage.

Answer (score 4):

You can do what you need in POSIX shell, but you must protect against numbers with leading zeros being interpreted as **octal** numbers. To do what you want, you need a way to remove the leading zeros for your conversion to a number. While bash provides a simple built-in parameter expansion that will work, in POSIX shell, you are stuck using the old `expr` syntax or calling a utility like `sed` or `grep`.

To trim the leading zeros using `expr`, you must first know how many there are. The old POSIX shell `expr` provides two expressions that will work. The first called `index` can return the index of the first character in `$input_sub` that is not `0`. Which gives you the index (1-based) where the first non-zero digit is found. The form you can use is:

```
    ## get index of first non-zero digit, POSIX compliant
    nonzero=$(expr index "$input_sub" [123456789])
```

With the index of the first non-zero digit in `$nonzero`, you can use the `substr` expression to obtain the number without leading zeros (you know the max number of digits is `3`, so obtain the substring from the index to `3`), e.g.

```
        num=$(expr substr "$input_sub" "$nonzero" 3)  ## remove leading 0's
```

You need to be able to handle `000` as `$inpu_sub`, so go ahead and add a `if .. then ... else ... fi` to handle that case, e.g.

```
    if [ "$nonzero" -eq 0 ]; then
        num=0
    else
        num=$(expr substr "$input_sub" "$nonzero" 3)  ## remove leading 0's
    fi
```

Now you can simply add `1` to get your new number:

```
    newnum=$((num + 1))
```

To convert the number back to a string of 3 characters representing the number with leading zeros replaced, just use `printf` with the `"%03d"` conversion specifier, e.g.

```
    # then convert that 1 to 001 
    input_sub=$(printf "%03d" "$newnum")
```

Putting together a short example showing the progression that takes place, I have replaced your while loop with a loop that will loop 21 times from `0` to `20` to show the operation and I have added `printf` statements to show the numbers and conversion back to string. You simply restore your `while` and remove the extra `printf` statements for your use:

```
#!/bin/sh

input_sub=000
# while [ -d $input_dir ]
while [ "$input_sub" != "020" ]    ## temporary loop 000 to 009
do
    printf "input_sub: %s  " "$input_sub"
    
    # HERE I would like to fist convert 000 to 0
    # then add 1 to it 0-> 1
    
    ## get index of first non-zero digit, POSIX compliant
    nonzero=$(expr index "$input_sub" [123456789])
    if [ "$nonzero" -eq 0 ]; then
        num=0
    else
        num=$(expr substr "$input_sub" "$nonzero" 3)  ## remove leading 0's
    fi
    newnum=$((num + 1))
    
    # then convert that 1 to 001 
    input_sub=$(printf "%03d" "$newnum")
    
    printf "%2d + 1 = %2d  =>  input_sub: %s\n" "$num" "$newnum" "$input_sub"
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

Showing the conversions with the modified `while` loop, you would get:

```
$ sh str2int2str.sh
input_sub: 000   0 + 1 =  1  =>  input_sub: 001
input_sub: 001   1 + 1 =  2  =>  input_sub: 002
input_sub: 002   2 + 1 =  3  =>  input_sub: 003
input_sub: 003   3 + 1 =  4  =>  input_sub: 004
input_sub: 004   4 + 1 =  5  =>  input_sub: 005
input_sub: 005   5 + 1 =  6  =>  input_sub: 006
input_sub: 006   6 + 1 =  7  =>  input_sub: 007
input_sub: 007   7 + 1 =  8  =>  input_sub: 008
input_sub: 008   8 + 1 =  9  =>  input_sub: 009
input_sub: 009   9 + 1 = 10  =>  input_sub: 010
input_sub: 010  10 + 1 = 11  =>  input_sub: 011
input_sub: 011  11 + 1 = 12  =>  input_sub: 012
input_sub: 012  12 + 1 = 13  =>  input_sub: 013
input_sub: 013  13 + 1 = 14  =>  input_sub: 014
input_sub: 014  14 + 1 = 15  =>  input_sub: 015
input_sub: 015  15 + 1 = 16  =>  input_sub: 016
input_sub: 016  16 + 1 = 17  =>  input_sub: 017
input_sub: 017  17 + 1 = 18  =>  input_sub: 018
input_sub: 018  18 + 1 = 19  =>  input_sub: 019
input_sub: 019  19 + 1 = 20  =>  input_sub: 020
```

This has been done in POSIX shell given your tag `[shell]`. If you have bash available, you can shorten and make the script a bit more efficient by using bash built-ins instead of `expr`. That said, for 1000 directories max -- you won't notice much difference. Let me know if you have further questions.

**Bash Solution Per-Request in Comment**

If you do have bash available, then the `[[ ... ]]` expression provides the `=~` operator which allows an extended REGEX match on the right hand side (e.g. `[[ $var =~ REGEX ]]`)  The REGEX can contain capture groups (parts of the REGEX enclosed by `(..)`), that are used to fill the `BASH_REMATCH` array where `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` contains the total expression matched and `${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ...` contain each captured part of the regex.

So using `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` with a capture on the number beginning with `[123456789]` will leave the wanted number in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` allowing you to compute the new number using the builtin, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

input_sub=000
# while [ -d $input_dir ]
while [ "$input_sub" != "020" ]     ## temporary loop 000 to 020
do
    printf "input_sub: %s  " "$input_sub"
    
    # HERE I would like to fist convert 000 to 0
    # then add 1 to it 0-> 1
    
    ## [[ .. =~ REGEX ]], captures between (...) in array BASH_REMATCH
    if [[ $input_sub =~ ^0*([123456789]+[0123456789]*)$ ]]
    then
        num=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}      ## use number if not all zeros
    else
        num=0                       ## handle 000 case
    fi
    newnum=$((num + 1))
    
    # then convert that 1 to 001 
    input_sub=$(printf "%03d" "$newnum")
    
    printf "%2d + 1 = %2d  =>  input_sub: %s\n" "$num" "$newnum" "$input_sub"
    
done
```

(same output)

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will add one tag bash. Could you comment a bit more about the last part (bash part)